# how to setup multiple log files on Laravel?

Tags: php, file, logging, laravel

I'm looking for solution of multiple log files on Laravel 4.2.

Right now, I'm using Laravel default setup which is log to `laravel.log` by `Log::error($exception);`.
I need a way to be able write to `laravel.log` file and add ability to write also to `mycustom.log` some of special errors which is more critical to me and i would like to classify in another log file.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple solution would be to register a log listener and do the saving yourself into `mycustom.log` if it matches your criteria. You can send additional data in the log `$context` variable.

```
Log::listen(function($level, $message, $context)
{
    // Save to mycustom.log
});
```

Laravel uses the [Monolog](https://github.com/Seldaek/monolog) logging library which contains plenty of other features though that you might want to look into. You can get an instance of Monolog by doing `Log::getMonolog()`.

Comment: How can I use existing monolog instance for another Logger?

Comment: I don't fully understand how you mean. If you mean a custom logger, you can do as I described?